# How can I prevent my while loop from causing an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

It appears that my while loop is causing an infinite loop, but when I step through it the loop seems to end appropriately. What am I not seeing? it seems to me that my else should iterate left to eventually equal 2 and then left is no longer less than right and it should just return nums.

```
function removeDuplicates(nums) {

   let left = 0;
   let right = nums.length - 1;


   while (left < right) {
       if (nums[left] !== nums[left + 1]) {
          nums.splice(nums[left], 1)
          nums.push("_")
       } else {
           left++            
       }

     }

     return nums;
}

removeDuplicates([1,1,2])
```

I expect the end result to return [1,2,"_"]

Comment: even if it doesn't end in an infinite loop this approach does not remove duplicates, this only removes immediate repetition.

Comment: `nums[left]` cannot be an argument to `nums.splice()` : it is a value, not a position.

Comment: @MisterJojo that value returns a number. The number can be used as a position.

Comment: try on `removeDuplicates([10,10,20])` -> there no `10` indexed element

Comment: Ah, I see your point. I have it working in my browser, but failing in LeetCode editor.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement was bad formulated. I exchange it with a `while`. You should splice and push "_" while`nums[left] === nums[left + 1]` and `nums[left] !== "_"`, else it would generate an infinite loop. Increase `left` no matter what after ending the nested while:

```js
function removeDuplicates(nums) {

  let left = 0;
  let right = nums.length - 1;

  while (left < right) {
    while (nums[left] === nums[left + 1] && nums[left] !== "_") {
      nums.splice(left, 1)
      nums.push("_")
    }
    left++
  }

  return nums;
}

console.log(removeDuplicates([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]))
```

Comment: This solution has the same problem. Try updating your answer to use the following numbers. [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]. You'll encounter the same problem.

Comment: `removeDuplicates([10,10,20])` make an infinite loop with your code

Comment: @MisterJojo I supossed OP want to use sorted array incremented by +1. Anyway it´s better to just index the splice using left variable

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop when `nums[left] == '_'` and  `nums[left +1] == '_'`
Do it this way...

```js
const removeDuplicates = nums =>
  {
  for (let left=0; left< nums.length -1;) 
    {
    if (nums[left] === '_' ) break     // to avoid infinite loop
    if (nums[left] === nums[left +1]) 
      {
      nums.splice( left, 1) // not  splice( nums[left]
      nums.push('_')
      } 
    else left++  
    }
  return nums;
  }


console.log('1,1,2->', JSON.stringify(removeDuplicates([1,1,2])))
console.log('10,10,20->', JSON.stringify(removeDuplicates([10,10,20])))
console.log('0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4->', JSON.stringify(removeDuplicates([0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4])))
 
console.log( JSON.stringify(removeDuplicates(['a','a','b','b','b','c','c','d','d','e'])))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
.as-console-row::after { display: none !important; }
```